Globally isometric surfaces
Let $S_{1}=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}:\dfrac{x^2}{4}+y^2=1\}$ and $S_{2}=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}:z=x^2\}$ be two regular surfaces

Are $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ locally isometric?
Are $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ globally isometric?

I have found that the gaussian curvatures $K_{1}=K_{2}=0$ so they're locally isometric. But I  don't really know how to see the second part. My guess is that $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ aren't globally isometric and may be because they aren't homeomorph. Is the idea good enough to prove it?

Both are cylinders, the first an elliptical cylinder, the second a parabolic cylinder. Your idea sounds promising. How will you show they are not globally homeomorphic?
